# How can I render a SVG based on ternary operator inside a JSX?

Tags: svg, jsx, stenciljs

I am using Stencil.js, but the syntax is similar to React.

```
const iconSVG = <svg>...</svg>

return (
      <button>
      {this.icon ?
       this.position === 'left'
        ? iconSVG `${this.label}`
        : `${this.label} icon` 
      : this.label}
      </button>
    );
```

This gives me an error:  `iconSVG is not a function`

```
return (
      <button>
      {this.icon ?
       this.position === 'left'
        ? <svg> ...</svg> `${this.label}`
        : `${this.label} icon` 
      : this.label}
      </button>
    );
```

This doesn't work because of the `this.label`. There can only be one element (value).

```
 return (
          <button>
          {this.icon ?
           this.position === 'left'
            ? `${<svg> ...</svg>} `${this.label}`
            : `${this.label} icon` 
          : this.label}
          </button>
        );
```

This gives me `[Object object]` inside the Button next to the `label`.

```
const iconSVG = () => <svg> ...</svg>

return (
      <button>
      {this.icon ?
       this.position === 'left'
        ? iconSVG() `${this.label}`
        : `${this.label} icon` 
      : this.label}
      </button>
    );
```

This gives me an error: `iconSVG(...) is not a function` obviously because the JSX is read first.

So, how do I do it? How can I render the `SVG` inside the JSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
return (
    <button>
        {this.icon && this.position === 'left' && <svg>...</svg>}
        {this.label}
        {this.icon && this.position !== 'left' && ' icon'}
    </button>
);
```

Comment: Yeah, this works, but is this the only solution? I don't like the duplicate code.

Comment: This is actually not going to work for me because I need to be able to align the label and the icon, so both need to be inside a single element.

Comment: just add a class `flex` with a condition

Answer (score 1):

Because you are specifying more than one item inside an expression, you need to use an array:

#1

```
render() {
    const iconSVG = <svg></svg>;
    return (
        <button>
            {this.icon ?
                this.position === 'left'
                    ? [iconSVG, this.label]
                    : `${this.label} icon`
                : this.label}
        </button>
    );
}
```

#2

```
render() {
    return (
        <button>
            {this.icon
                ? this.position === 'left'
                    ? [<svg> ...</svg>, this.label]
                    : `${this.label} icon`
                : this.label}
        </button>
    );
}
```

#3 would be the same as #2.

#4

```
render() {
    const iconSVG = () => <svg> ...</svg>;

    return (
        <button>
            {this.icon
                ? this.position === 'left'
                    ? [iconSVG(), this.label]
                    : `${this.label} icon`
                : this.label
            }
        </button>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your svg as following.

```
export const IconSvg = () => {
  return (
      <svg>
        ...
      </svg>
  );
};
```

And then , used with your ternary operator.

eg.

```
import React from "react";

const isRed = true;

export const RedIconSvg = () => {
  return (
      <svg width="100" height="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" />
      </svg>
  );
};

export const BlueIconSvg = () => {
  return (
      <svg width="100" height="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="blue" />
      </svg>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isRed ? <RedIconSvg/> : <BlueIconSvg/>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where are you exporting this function from, and how do you use it inside the ternary operator??

Comment: Please kindly check again my answered. I wrote an example for you.

Comment: Where is the `this.label` in your JSX? You are rendering a single svg component, but I am rendering two items! I need the `this.label` next to the svg.

Comment: What is the value of this.lable ? You can also render in my svg component . Do you got it ? If you don't know how to do it, please let me know.

Comment: The value of `this.label` is passed as a prop. It doesn't matter what it is. It has to be there. You cannot have it inside a svg.

Comment: Also, in `Stenci.js` you cannot define components inside a component, and then render them like you have.